# Excel 2010 - Remove all duplicates BUT ONE

Tags: excel

After searching through the forums, I am unable to find out how to accomplish this.

**Columns:**

Supervisor - Date - Employee - QA Specialist Name

**Data:**

Dave - 10/10/2010 18:29:34 - Tommy - Jen

Dave - 10/10/2010 18:29:34 - Tommy - Jen

Sara - 10/10/2010 18:30:15 - Jonny - Bob

**'Remove Duplicates' leaves me with:**

Sara - 10/10/2010 18:30:15 - Jonny - Bob

**I want:**

Dave - 10/10/2010 18:29:34 - Tommy - Jen

Sara - 10/10/2010 18:30:15 - Jonny - Bob

Since Microsoft decided to misname this function, how would I actually go about deleting only the duplicated rows?  I have thousands of rows of data, so doing this manually is not feasable.  Also, I only have Excel to work with using this.

*Note: This was after doing my best to get the answer from the forums.  This was also after several hours of fighting Excel.  I'm pretty much all out of luck at this point.

Comment: This is the default behavior of Excel. Try it on a single column of a brand new spreadsheet ("Dave", "Dave", "Sara"). Please provide additional details about your spreadsheet setup.

Comment: Remove duplicates on the date/time stamp did not remove both Dave's entries for me.

Comment: Why not just make a pivot table?  This will remove duplicates automatically.

Comment: Having the Date column entered in simply as 'General' first, then changing it to Text (xxxxx.xxxxx) allows me to get exactly what I want.  I tried this in my 'sterile' example above and it gave me Sarah and only one Dave.  Thank you for the help! :-)

Comment: @mmarie: Because, some in my organization weren't too satisfied with that approach ;-p

Answer (score -1):

Form an extra column that has all the data from the other columns concatenated after each other. Write a formula in the column after to count if the value in the range from the top row till the current row is equal to the current row (this will indicate that a count of 2 or more shows that this is a duplicate row). Filter on the column to look for counts that are 2 or more and delete those rows. Delete the two extra rows added.